# pandas apply decimal in column with numbers and strings

Tags: python, pandas, decimal, apply, series

I have a column which contains numbers and strings. E.g:

```
Result:
Failed
8.05
9
7
```

How can I change the data to show two decimals i.e. as following?

```
Result:
Failed
8.05
9.00
7.00
```

I am trying the following but it doesn't work. Thanks for your help!

```
df['Result'] =  df['Result'].apply('{:.2f}'.format)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `pd.Series.apply` with a ternary expression:

```
s = pd.Series(['Failed', 8.05, 9, 7])

s =  s.apply(lambda x: f'{x:.2f}' if not isinstance(x, str) else x)

print(s)

0    Failed
1      8.05
2      9.00
3      7.00
dtype: object
```

Note this is not a recommended way to structure your data as you are mixing numeric and non-numeric types. In addition, you are storing numeric data as strings, which is expensive.

Answer (score 2):

I think need create boolean mask:

```
#numeric with strings
df = pd.DataFrame({'Result':['Failed',8.05,9,7]})

mask = pd.to_numeric(df['Result'], errors='coerce').notnull()
df.loc[mask, 'Result'] =  df.loc[mask, 'Result'].apply('{:.2f}'.format)
print (df)
0  Failed
1    8.05
2    9.00
3    7.00
```

If all strings is necessary first cast to `float`s:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Result':['Failed','8.05','9','7']})

mask = pd.to_numeric(df['Result'], errors='coerce').notnull()
df.loc[mask, 'Result'] =  df.loc[mask, 'Result'].astype(float).apply('{:.2f}'.format)
print (df)
   Result
0  Failed
1    8.05
2    9.00
3    7.00
```

Comment: Thanks for your effort. I would like though to keep the str in the column. in your solution the "Failed" disappears.